# Getting a TypeError when trying to extract strings from 2D Arrays in AppsScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a program that will go through each cell in a few columns in a Google Sheets File (Sheet1) and compare the value in those cells to the values in other columns in a different Google Sheets File (Sheet2). If a cell value from Sheet1 can be found in Sheet2, the script will delete the row that has that value from Sheet1. I'm using the `.getRange()` function to get a 2D array of all the values in each column. The problem is, when I try to extract the string value from each individual array within the 2d array, it's giving me this Error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`

Here's the code I tried:

```
function CheckDNCList(string){
  id = 'SHEET2_ID'
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss)
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var num_rows = sheet.getLastRow().toString();
  var num_rows = num_rows.replace(".0","");
  var ret_val = false
  for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++){
    values = sheet.getRange(1,i,num_rows,1).getValues()
    for(var j = 0; j < values.length; j++){
      if (values[j].includes(string )){
        var ret_val = true
    }
  }
  }
  return ret_val;
}

function dropRowsFromLeadSheet(){
  var ls_id = 'SHEET1_ID';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ls_id);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var num_rows = sheet.getLastRow().toString(); //gets row count of 
  var num_rows = num_rows.replace(".0","");
  for (var i = 5; i < 7; i++){
    values = sheet.getRange(1,i,num_rows,1).getValues() //gives me a 2D array of all the values in the column
    for(var j = values.length; j>=0; j--){ //had to go from bottom up because of how Google sheets works
      var array = values[j] //getting each individual array within the 2D array
      if(typeof array !== null){
        if(array.length == 1) { // <---- Here is where the error says the code is breaking
          var string = array[0]
          if(CheckDNCList(string)){
            sheet.deleteRow(j)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I assumed that since the length command wasn't working that one of the values in the 2D Array was a null or something, but I wrote a loop to add all the unique types to an array and the only value in the array was `object`. Since I'm only pulling a single column with the `getRange()` command, the length should always be 1 or 0. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: num_rows should be an integer

Comment: I tried that. same error :/ . I don't think that's the issue because I checked the value of array for each cell using .log and they were showing the strings within the array, for some reason it just isn't taking the string out of the array.  The problem seems to lie in the dropFromLeadSheet function

Comment: That may not be your current problem but it is a problem.  Check the parameters for a getRange and you will see.

Comment: Your code seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're only presenting the error in your code without showing the people in the community the whole picture. Kindly add a sample data so that the community can quickly reproduce the error. That way, it can be easily dissected. Just letting people look at your script won't help them give you an accurate answer. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

When using `console.log` to see the value of `j` and `values`, it looks like `j` is out of the range of `values`. This is because in the for loop, you designed `j` as `values.length`, but in JavaScript (and Google Apps Script) arrays are zero-indexed, so `values.length` is one index outside of `values`.

This can be fixed by changing the for loop to `for (var j = values.length - 1; j >=0; j--) {...`, which works fine through the first pass, where `j` is the last index, but fails on the second pass.

Using the debug function in the Google Apps Script editor, we can see that after running `CheckDNCList(string)`, `values` is messed up and no longer contains the correct information. This is because line 10 of the `CheckDNCList` function says `values = sheet.getRange(1, i, num_rows, 1).getValues()`. Because there is no `let` or `var` or `const` keyword before `values`, the Global variable `values` is changed. In JavaScript, `let` is mostly used for variables inside of functions. If we change line 10 to `let values = sheet.getRange(1,i,num_rows,1).getValues()` the code runs with no errors.

The working code with minimal changes is this:

```
function CheckDNCList(string){
  let id = 'SHEET2_ID' // add let keyword
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss)
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var num_rows = sheet.getLastRow().toString();
  var num_rows = num_rows.replace(".0","");
  var ret_val = false
  for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++){
    let values = sheet.getRange(1,i,num_rows,1).getValues() // add let keyword
    for(var j = 0; j < values.length; j++){
      if (values[j].includes(string )){
        var ret_val = true
    }
  }
  }
  return ret_val;
}

function dropRowsFromLeadSheet(){
  var ls_id = 'SHEET1_ID';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ls_id);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var num_rows = sheet.getLastRow().toString();
  var num_rows = num_rows.replace(".0","");
  for (var i = 5; i < 7; i++){
    let values = sheet.getRange(1,i,num_rows,1).getValues() // add 'let' keyword
    for(var j = values.length - 1; j>=0; j--){ // changed values.length to values.length - 1
      var array = values[j]
      if(typeof array !== null){
        if(array.length == 1) {
          var string = array[0]
          if(CheckDNCList(string)){
            sheet.deleteRow(j)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A more standard version of the code would look like this:

```
function CheckDNCList(string) {
  const id = 'SHEET2_ID';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  let num_rows = sheet.getLastRow().toString();
  num_rows = num_rows.replace(".0", "");
  for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    let values = sheet.getRange(1, i, num_rows, 1).getValues();
    for(let j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
      if (values[j].includes(string )){
        return(true); // since there only needs to be one of the values found, we can just return true on the first value found
    }
  }
  }
  return(false); // if we are here, it means there was no value found, so we don't even need the 'ret_val' variable
}

function dropRowsFromLeadSheet() {
  const ls_id = 'SHEET1_ID';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ls_id);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  let num_rows = sheet.getLastRow().toString();
  num_rows = num_rows.replace(".0", "");
  for (let i = 5; i < 7; i++){
    let values = sheet.getRange(1, i, num_rows, 1).getValues()
    for(let j = values.length - 1; j>=0; j--){
      let array = values[j]
      if(typeof array !== null){
        if(array.length == 1) {
          var string = array[0];
          if(CheckDNCList(string)){
            sheet.deleteRow(j);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```